# What is the right way to combine kafka producer transaction and JPA transaction

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-data-jpa, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

I use these code to combine JPA and kafka-producer transaction:

```
val template = TrasactionTemplate(txnManager) // JpaTransactionManager
template.execute {
    dbrepo.save(record)
    myproducer.send(record)
}
```

If the code throws any exception before it exits the execute scope{}, both db and kafka can be rollback.

If during the commit stage,  db is committed first but kafka get `ProducerFencedException` or other `node disconnnected` error, kafka won't produce the event, however, db can't be rollbacked(the record is already stored in table)

My question is:

- I am going to use `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` to solve it, will it work?
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1699 mentioned `ChainedKafkaTransactionManager` depreciated, so what is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommend approach, without needing Spring features, would be always write to the system that's more highly available. In most cases, that's Kafka (can still be transactional Kafka producer, but you don't need JPA for that). Then you write a Kafka consumer, in the app, or elsewhere (such as Kafka Connect) that consumes those records and updates the database.

Alternatively, if the database is more highly available, use CDC or the "outbox pattern" along with tools such as Debezium to read database events into Kafka.